# Warping Matplotlib/Seaborn Scatter Plot into Parallelogram

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have a 2D scatterplot (in either matplotlib or seaborn) and an angle e.g. 64 degrees. I want to plot a warped version of this scatter plot where the x-axis of the first plot is held fixed but the second axis is warped such that the y-axis of the first plot is now at the given angle with the x-axis of the new plot (i.e. 64 degrees). How can I do this?

In other words, I want to take the original scatter plot and "push" the y-axis to the right to form a parallelogram-like plot where the angle between the old y axis and the old/new x-axis is the given angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaption of [an old tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/axes_grid/demo_floating_axes.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
skewed_transform = Affine2D().skew_deg(90 - 64, 0)
grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(skewed_transform, extremes=(-0.5, 1.5, -0.5, 1.5))
skewed_ax = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, 111, grid_helper=grid_helper)
skewed_ax.set_facecolor('0.95')  # light grey background
skewed_ax.axis["top"].set_visible(False)
skewed_ax.axis["right"].set_visible(False)
fig.add_subplot(skewed_ax)
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100)  # random point in a square of [0,1]x[0,1]
skewed_ax.scatter(x, y, transform=skewed_transform + skewed_ax.transData)
plt.show()
```

[image: skewed ax]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!!

Comment: How do I also skew the scatter plot data? When I try `skewed_ax.scatter(x, y)`, the points aren't similarly skewed.

Comment: I added some demo data with the same skew on the scatter plot.  You might want to add your own test data and example plot to your question to help clarify what exactly you need.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!