# Rotate one axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some series x and y such that x+y ≤ 1. If I make a simple scatter plot it looks like this:

[image: scatter plot]

I'd like to transform this plot so that the angle between the positive x and y axes is 60 degrees rather than 90 degrees. Basically I want the fundamental region bounded by the origin and (1,0) and (0,1) to be transformed from an isosceles right triangle to an equilateral triangle.

Through various web searches (including [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-rotate-a-simple-matplotlib-axes)) this is the closest I can come up with:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes

fig = plt.figure()
plot_extents = 0, 1, 0, 1
transform = Affine2D().skew_deg(30,0).scale(1,0.8660254038)
helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(transform, plot_extents)
ax = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, 111, grid_helper=helper)

x = [0.41729137, 0.31693662, 0.25544209, 0.13843966, 0.31218805,0.01035702, 0.4847026 , 0.11104309, 0.25144685, 0.18332651]
y = [0.20372773, 0.5395082 , 0.6020569 , 0.19787512, 0.57743819,0.93317626, 0.43035489, 0.8235019 , 0.36000727, 0.24365175]
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.set_xlim(-0.15,1.15)
ax.set_ylim(-0.15,1.15)
fig.add_axes(ax)
```

But the result seems to keep the points where they are and only move the one axis.

[image: second attempt]

Comment: See [Warping Matplotlib/Seaborn Scatter Plot into Parallelogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660368/warping-matplotlib-seaborn-scatter-plot-into-parallelogram).  It uses `scatter(x, y, transform=transform + ax.transData)`.

Comment: @JohanC that's the ticket. I didn't think of searching for "warp."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohanC for the pointer to [his answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68664166/297797). The part I was missing is that the axes' current transformation needs to be added to the desired transformation.

```py
r = np.random.rand(3,10)
x = r[0]/(r[0]+r[1]+r[2])
y = r[1]/(r[0]+r[1]+r[2])

fig = plt.figure()
plot_extents = 0, 1, 0, 1
transform = Affine2D().skew_deg(30,0).scale(1,0.8660254038)
helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(transform, plot_extents)
ax = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, 111, grid_helper=helper)


ax.scatter(x,y,transform = ax.transData + transform)
ax.set_xlim(-0.15,1.15)
ax.set_ylim(-0.15,1.15)
fig.add_axes(ax)
```

[image: successful plot]

I need to prettify it some more, but this solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the rotate_deg(120) method to the transform transformation,
to rotate the coordinate system:

```py
transform = Affine2D().skew_deg(60, 0).scale(1, 0.8660254038).rotate_deg(120)
```

Here is the code of this method:

```py
def rotate_deg(self, degrees):
    """
    Add a rotation (in degrees) to this transform in place.

    Returns *self*, so this method can easily be chained with more
    calls to :meth:`rotate`, :meth:`rotate_deg`, :meth:`translate`
    and :meth:`scale`.
    """
    return self.rotate(math.radians(degrees))
```

*According to the documentation lines, this should be the solution.*

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't work.

Comment: I have completed the answer.

It seems to me that this is the right direction.
Look at the other methods of the class:
`Affine2D`

Comment: I tried several solutions by varying just the transformation. The part I was missing is that the `transform` had to be passed to the `scatterplot` call, and also that it had to be added to the axes' current transformation. If you have a simpler solution I'd love to see a working example.